# PDF.JS using its library to a site from another site within the same server?

Tags: javascript, server

I have 2 sites in the same server (one site is a framework and the other a frontend). The directories where the files reside are in the root of the server: FrontEnd and Framework_Acme
I installed pdf.js in the FrontEnd directory with a subdirectory named Pdfjs. I implemented the code in javascript in an .asp inside the FrontEnd directory. But I need to move the PDF library to Framework_Acme because I will open another site soon and for sake o centralization. How can I point to the pdf.js library in the Framework_Acme using the .asp located in FrontEnd?

```
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf']; <- How can I change this? It only works if the library is inside the FrontEnd site.
        
        //Extension pdf.js (pdf.worker.js)
        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = './pdfjs/pdf.worker.js';
    
        //Async PDF
        var LoadTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(PDF_URL);
...
```

Comment: Why are you tagging this with `pdf.js` (removed), it's not like this was a problem specific to that particular library, you would be having the exact same issue with _any_ other script you want to embed.

Comment: @ObaidaAlhassan I never need to do that. It always worked just by putting the library inside a directory in the FrontEnd root. It works 100%. But I need to put the library in the Framework_Acme and link it in the .asp in the FrontEnd directory.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you need a way to embed the library in your FE app using .asp, correct? 
Why do you just target the pdflib using CDN? On FE we don't have access to the file system to read from outside folders

Comment: I was trying to tell you to please tag _appropriately_. The tag `pdf.js` makes little sense here - you do not have a problem with that library or its functionality itself, you have a problem with embedding the script file correctly within your server-side setup. That problem would be the same with _any other_ JS library, so it simply makes no sense to tag this question here with `pdf.js`, because the whole problem isn't specific to that to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Ah ok, yes, you're right. Sorry me. Thanks for the warning

Comment: @ObaidaAlhassan I know, but can't I do that instead using the CDN directive? I always avoid that, becoming dependent of other external entities....

Comment: You have a dependency on the FE library `pdfjs` but since you don't share the `window` object between your /asp and FE app you cannot inject the library in the window by .asp "like what Blazor WASM offer"

Comment: @ObaidaAlhassan I know that, but you mean there's no other way?

Comment: Have you tried to request the library using `<script>` tag with full file path e.g:

`<script src= "C:/myApp/ASPApp/pdflib.js" </script>`

Comment: @ObaidaAlhassan Actually multiple .asp pages will call the function that's in another .js (The code I presented)

Comment: What kind of app you are building, MVC-SPA-Static? are you using Blazor 
what is the way your asp can call .js content-methods?

please attach your asp framework link, and I believe your FE is static, HTML-CSS-JS without task runner or bundler, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238316/discussion-between-obaida-alhassan-and-joao).

Answer (score -2):

Resolved - a mix up in a variable took me to bad paths...

Comment: Hi! You should explain in your answer what you did to resolve it. Otherwise delete the question if you don't want to provide an answer.